# Which key is Insert on Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop

I use my Mac connected to a remote server (Windows 2008) using Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta, and in the Windows 2008, there is a virtual machine on it, I use the Xshell connected to the VM.

But when I want to paste some code, the shortcut key is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, however on the Mac there is no <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. How can I use the shortcut key to paste my code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to use an insert key with Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta.

The UserVoice request has a few votes: [Create a shortcut for the insert key function in Mac - Customer Feedback for Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/287834-remote-desktop-for-mac/suggestions/17188697-create-a-shortcut-for-the-insert-key-function-in-m)

Comment: I find a easy way to paste text in the Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta on mac, is use three finger tap the touch board.

Comment: @aircraft Excellent — yes, you can perform a middle click with a three finger tap, so if the app implements middle click as paste, then you can paste using that.

Comment: The pain of re-indoctrination...

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this issue and had to experiment a bit until I found a solution. Using a [Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english), I am able to send an insert key by pressing <kbd>clear</kbd> to toggle the number lock on (depending on what application you're using, there may not be any feedback), then pressing <kbd>0</kbd> on the number pad:

[image: clear+0]

I'm not sure if the same trick would work on other keyboards, or how you would do this without a number pad, but hopefully this helps some users.

Comment: This works for me.  How did you discover it?

Comment: @BitRocker I just looked where the numlock was on a Microsoft keyboard, and took a few wild guesses (I think I tried `fn`+`clear`, `command`+`clear` etc.) until I eventually found one that worked.

Comment: The `fn+Enter` combination on a mac keyboard toggles between insert and normal typing mode for me.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is still a problem. But I solved it by using the onscreen keyboard in Windows 10.